# Database too large to handle? C# or OLEDBCommand

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I have created a fairly simple program to handle Reports on an annual basis. Until recently it worked, but as the Access Database increased in size, the program eventually stopped working. When I shrink the database in a test environment, it continues to work as expected.

```
public List<WorkOrderModel> getAllWorkOrdersForYear(int year)
    {
        List<WorkOrderModel> workOrderList = new List<WorkOrderModel>();
        conn = null;
        //int connectionOpen = openConnection();
        openConnection();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            result = -1;
            string sql;
            string selectedDate = "04/30/" + (year);
            string endDate = "05/01/" + (year + 1);

            sql = "SELECT * FROM WorkOrder WHERE NOT Completed = 0 AND dateCompleted > #" 
                            + selectedDate + "# AND dateCompleted < #" 
                            + endDate + "# ORDER BY supervisor ASC;";

            // load up and execute sql command
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            try
            {
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // error close the connection
                conn.Close();
                Console.Write("Error - " + ex.Message);
                return workOrderList;
            }

            // successfully got data
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                WorkOrderModel wom;
                int num;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Note: try/catch's for fields with possible null/empty returns
                    num = 0;
                    // create a new workOrderModel object
                    wom = new WorkOrderModel();

                    // load up the object with values
                    wom.setWorkOrderNumber((int)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setUserID((int)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setFirstName(reader.GetString(num++));
                    wom.setLastName(reader.GetString(num++));
                    wom.setDateSubmitted(reader.GetDateTime(num++));
                    wom.setCustNum(reader.GetString(num++));
                    wom.setEquipment(reader.GetString(num++));
                    wom.setDescription(reader.GetString(num++));
                    // tech
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setTech(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setTech(""); }
                    wom.setLabour((double)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setShopFee((double)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setHardware((double)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setElectronicComponets((double)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setMaterials((double)reader.GetValue(num++));
                    wom.setLabourCost((double)reader.GetDecimal(num++));
                    wom.setSuppliesCost((double)reader.GetDecimal(num++));
                    wom.setTotalCost((double)reader.GetDecimal(num++));
                    // work performed
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setWorkPerformed(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setWorkPerformed(""); }

                    // date completed
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setDateCompleted(reader.GetDateTime(num++));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        DateTime tempDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                        wom.setDateCompleted(tempDate);
                    }
                    // completion flag
                    wom.setIsComplete(reader.GetBoolean(num++));
                    //phone
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setPhone(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setPhone(""); }

                    //email
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setEmail(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setEmail(""); }

                    // department
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setDepartment(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setDepartment(""); }

                    // supervisor
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setSupervisor(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch { wom.setSupervisor(""); }
                    // affiliate
                    wom.setAffiliate(reader.GetBoolean(num++));
                    wom.setBilling(reader.GetBoolean(num++));
                    wom.setStatus(reader.GetBoolean(num++));

                    try
                    {
                        wom.setStatusValue(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        wom.setStatusValue("");
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        wom.setBillingFile(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        wom.setBillingFile("");
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        wom.setCommon(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        wom.setCommon("");
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        wom.setSection(reader.GetString(num++));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        wom.setSection("");
                    }

                    //cust = wom.getCustNum();

                    // get any extras for each order if the exist
                    sql = "SELECT * FROM Extra WHERE orderID = " + wom.getWorkOrderNumber();
                    OleDbDataReader extrasReader;

                    // are there any extras attached to the work order
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
                    try
                    {
                        extrasReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                    catch { extrasReader = null; }

                    // has values
                    if (extrasReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        ExtraModel extra;
                        List<ExtraModel> extList = new List<ExtraModel>();
                        while (extrasReader.Read())
                        {
                            extra = new ExtraModel();
                            extra.setOrderID((int)extrasReader.GetValue(1));
                            extra.setDescription(extrasReader.GetString(2));
                            extra.setPrice((double)extrasReader.GetDecimal(3));
                            extList.Add(extra);
                        }
                        wom.setExtras(extList);
                    }
                    // add object to list
                    workOrderList.Add(wom);
                }
            }// if
            // close connection and return list
            conn.Close();
            return workOrderList;
        }
        else
        {
            workOrderList = null;
            return workOrderList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "stopped working" is a very vague description of what happened. How many rows are you trying to process, and what *does* happen?

Comment: Access....that is your problem right there. It is a personal database with serious limitations and has many issues with db corruption, growing file sizes, limited multi user support etc. . at a minimum go to SQL Server Express.

Comment: Is it really necessary to read everything into memory and return a list? Can't you process the rows as you read them?

Comment: Currently I'm processing 1000 rows with 32 columns. The program crashes when it exceeds approximately 700 rows

Comment: While I agree that Access is not the best tool for many db related works I really hate this bashing against it without knowing anything of the context

Comment: The biggest problem here is I'm the junior systems admin, and the person who wrote this program left 8 months ago. I have been doing some simple bug fixes, but am unsure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you really need to select _all_ fields from the table? Also does your table hold some Large Object type columns ?

Comment: @AndrewWall 1000 rows are hardly a memory problem here. But you don't address the second part of the clarification requested. What does happen? What is the error message received?

Comment: I don't need to select all of the fields, just 10 as far as I'm aware. and yes, there are several description columns that can contain quite a few characters (>200)

Comment: The program crashes, with a general Windows "Program has stopped working"

Comment: There you go, it's the first sign of a bad design that you (or someone else) lazily selects `*` from any table, try optimizing it as you only select the columns you _need_ to process...

Comment: I see two `Select *`'s in the chunk of code you've posted.  That's the problem.  In place, specify only the fields that you are ACTUALLY making use of.  Realistically, although access isn't really an ideal tool, this shouldn't be choking if you simply swap that out (as a quick fix anyways - you really should look at porting it over to a proper architecture if it has the potential to grow much more though).

Comment: I suggest to remove all those try/catch and use the proper way to handle null values from the DbReader: _wom.setTech(reader.IsDbNull(num) ? "": reader.GetString(num)); num++;_ If you have many nulls, you will be surprised by speed gain of your code

Comment: Why did that guy place a try catch around each set value for a string in the WorkOrder but not follow the same wonky paradigm in the extra.setDescription(extrasReader.GetString(2))? If it throws an exception because it is null, what happens to your loop, or can it not be null?

Comment: That value can't be null,

Comment: I think the solution was to just grab the columns I needed. I took out the extra reader and simplified it a lot.

Comment: I thank everyone for the help. I've only learned Java in the past, this isn't really my field of expertise as I've only dabbled slightly into C#. So once again, thank you!

Comment: @AndrewWall - cool, but you should look at the advice some of the others have provided (particularly abut the null checks, hitting against a catch statement is rather expensive, as far as process time goes)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your loop, you create another `OleDbCommand`, and a reader, but you never close them, this means you leave a cursor open on the database.

`Close`/`Dispose` the extra reader & command when you are done with them, or better, use the `using` syntax.

And you re-use the `cmd` object for the extra reader. I don't know if this is wrong, but it is ugly.

```
                // are there any extras attached to the work order
                using (var cmdExtras = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) 
                using (var extrasReader = cmdExtras.ExecuteReader()) {

                    ExtraModel extra;
                    List<ExtraModel> extList = new List<ExtraModel>();
                    while (extrasReader.Read())
                    {
                        extra = new ExtraModel();
                        extra.setOrderID((int)extrasReader.GetValue(1));
                        extra.setDescription(extrasReader.GetString(2));
                        extra.setPrice((double)extrasReader.GetDecimal(3));
                        extList.Add(extra);
                    }
                    if (extList.Any()) wom.setExtras(extList);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the others that replacing Access should be on this program's development roadmap, from experience this load alone shouldn't cause it to fail.

We don't yet have enough information to fix it, so here's what I'd do to move towards a fix.

1. Replace the SELECT * queries with actual field lists
2. Upgrde the try..catch blocks to log more information, including InnerExceptions as given.
3. Add a TOP parameter into the query so you can find out exactly how many records cause it to fail. When you've found your magic First Record That Fails, tweak the query to return just that one record. Is it definitely the volume that's causing the problem, or is it the individual record?

Hopefully that lot should point you towards the root cause and get you a fix.